# 'Service1.InsertSupplier(Supplier)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, path, return

```
public int InsertSupplier(Supplier supplier)
{
    try
    {
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SupplierTable(@sup_id, @Supplier_Name, @Address, @City, @Phone, @Email, @TIN)";
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("sup_id", supplier.id);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Supplier_Name", supplier.NameSupplier);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", supplier.Address);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", supplier.City);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", supplier.Phone);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", supplier.Email);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("TIN", supplier.TIN);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();

        return comm.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, if you don't do anything in a catch block then do not write the catch at all. Second, if the code enters the catch block what value you want to return?

Comment: third: apply the [_using statement_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around the SqlConnection instead of the verbose try/finally and do not keep a global connection object

Answer (score 0):

In case of exception occurence your method return without `return`.

Add something like `return -1;` at the end:

```
public int InsertSupplier(Supplier supplier)
{
    try
    {
        // your code here
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }    
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return -1; // or change this to more proper value
}
```